# How many epimorphisms from $F_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, free-groups, free-abelian-group

> How many epimorphisms are there  from $F_2$ (the free group with $2$ generators) to $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

If $F_2$ is generated by $2$ elements, so it has a basis of rank$2$, meaning that it is isomorphic to$\mathbb{Z}_2$, and therefore cannot be any epimorphisms to $\mathbb{Z}_5$..

Is this correct?

Comment: your notation seem a little confused. The free group on two generators is not abelian, do you mean the free abelian group? Also $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is often used to denote the cyclic group of order $n$, but you seem to have denoted the free abelian group on two generators by $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so people will be confused what $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not correct, because a free group has no relations by definition and therefore it is not abelian, and cannot be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$.

Hint: say $F_2=\langle a,b\mid \, \rangle $.

- A homomorphism $F_2\to \Bbb Z_5$ is entirely determined by the image of $a$ and $b$, which can be anything and are independent.
- How many homomorphisms are *not* surjective?

Answer (score -1):

The group $F_2 = \langle{x_1, x_2\rangle}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$; it is free, infinite, and nonabelian. By definition, the map $\operatorname{Hom(F_2, \mathbb{Z}_5}) \to \mathbb{Z_5}^2$ given by $f \to (f(x_1), f(x_2))$ is an isomorphism. Since $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is cyclic of prime order, such a map $f:F_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_5$ fails to be surjective iff $f(x_1), f(x_2) = 0$.

Comment: So how can I know how many such homomorphisms are there where at least one of $f(x_1),f(x_2) \neq 0$?

Comment: It's $5^2-1=24$. Think about it.

Comment: $5$ epimophisms where where $x_1$ get to some element in $\mathbb{Z_5}$ which is not $0$, another such $5$ for $x_2$, gives us $5^2$? Minus one  homomorphism  where both $x_1,x_2$ go to 0?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this answer?

Comment: @anomaly I don't know who downvoted it... I believe that your answer is correct... Is my calculation correct?